# TypeError: mongoose.schema is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    brand: String
}, {
    timestamps: true
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Above is my code which I have written for learning can anyone pls help me solve the Error I'm facing

Comment: I think that should be uppercase `Schema` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be mongoose.Schema()!

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same problem. The word "Schema" should start with capital letter 'S' to avoid this error. Once you change the 'mongoose.schema' to 'mongoose.Schema' it will work just fine.

```
const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    price: Number,
    brand: String
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```